# Objective C Introspection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, introspection

When performing introspection on a class, I use the following code:

```
if([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){

        NSLog(@"I am an NSNumber: %@", object);
    }

 NSLog(@"Properties:%@", [object class]);
```

The output is:

```
I am an NSNumber: 320
Properties:__NSCFNumber
```

Can anyone explain why the result is __NSCFNumber for type NSNumber? I also noticed NSArray is identified as:

```
__NSArrayI
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSNumber` is a [class cluster.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34)  NSNumber is the abstract, public superclass of several concrete subclasses.  When you create an `NSNumber` with any of the `+numberWith...` methods, you will get an instance of one of these subclasses.

When you pass an object to NSLog() as a parameter corresponding to a "%@" storage  specifier, `NSLog()` will send that object a `-description` message, and insert whatever's returned from that message expression into the string it writes to the stderr  file descriptor.

Comment: Also, I would imagine that `__NSCFNumber` specifically derives from the toll-free-bridging between `NSNumber` and `CFNumber`. Similar results occur from `[@"" class]` (`__NSCFString`).

Comment: There's also "toll-free bridging", which accounts for the funny NSCFNumber class name, since essentially the same class exists in the Objective-C environment (NS) and the Core Foundation environment (CF), and the two can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense. I come from a Java and C# background, where  it's essentially like "programming to the interface" (if I understand correctly)

Comment: Sort of;  it is more straightforward.  In class clusters, you typically talk to an abstract class that, upon instantiation, returns an instance of some private subclass that is optimal for the requested configuration.   You shouldn't have to care -- or even know -- that this is happening.

Answer (score 4):

`__NSCFNumber` is a *private subclass* of `NSNumber`. You shouldn't have to worry what specific class is being used internally, it's an implementation detail that the OS uses to improve performance.

There are a number of classes that use this pattern (it's called a [Class Cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34)), including `NSString` and `NSArray`.

Looking too deeply into what actual type is being used is not recommended, as the types/implementations can (and do) change frequently. Just treat it as an `NSNumber` and you should be just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I can't directly answer your question, what I can tell you is that you could do this:

```
NSLog@"Class name: %@.", NSStringFromClass([object class]);
```

And you would get:

```
Class name: NSNumber.
```

Would that help you?